# Warning updating Kotlin : File extension '*.klib' was reassigned to 'ARCHIVE'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When updating Kotlin this morning, Android Studio gave me this warning:

> 10:38 AM  File type recognized: File extension '*.klib' was reassigned
> to 'ARCHIVE' **Revert to plain text**

What exactly does this message mean? Should I revert it to plain text?

Answer (score 4):

[*.klib files](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-libraries.html) are libraries that have been produced with the Kotlin/Native compiler. Thus they are correctly classified as a type of archive.

I received the same message while updating Kotlin, and I think that the message is should simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Android Studio` doesn't recognizes references (imports) from `klib` files, then you have to check your file type associations and add `*.klib` to Archive file type. Then click on `File` -> `Invalidate Cache / Restart`. It should start working.